# application release version couldn't install on marshmallow code

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-install-apk

When i use `./gradlew assembleDebug` and generate debug version of application it's install correctly but when i use `./gradlew assembleRelease` and generate release version app couldn't be install in android v.6 "Marshmallow".whats wrong with this?  this my `gradle.build` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'eCommerce Social Network'
            keyPassword '*****************'
            storeFile file('/home/saeed/Keys/ShareIno/sharino.jks')
            storePassword '!@#$s@EED 13710554$#@!'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shareino.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}

//compile 'com.labo.kaji:fragmentanimations:0.1.0'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
    compile 'com.appsee:appsee-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Any error you found?

Comment: @AndiGeeky  it doesn't show any error in logcat  just say app cant install

Comment: Can you add your app-module level `gradle` here?

Comment: i added this file, @AndiGeeky